# How the rename all columns using regular expression in Python?

Tags: python

I have columns in `pandas` data frame that look like:

```
Variable Names    
name1 [a]

name2 [b]

name3 [c]
```

I am using the following code to remove all the square brackets and everything within those brackets from all the variable names. This is the code I am using:

```
import re 
df = df.rename(columns=lambda n: n.replace(r'[\d+.*', r''))
```

This code is not working. How can I modify this code to get it to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you are looking for.

```
df.rename(columns=lambda x: re.sub("[\[].*?[\]]", "", x))
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if it works for you. Thanks